# MovementScale in PoseController script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-code, google-project-tango, rigid-bodies

I was playing around with the following CodeLab -https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/project-tango#5 and was trying to apply Tango Pose control to my player rigidbody (PoseController.cs). Although I do no understand why do we have to multiply 'new_position' with 'm_movementScale'? Also when I make my movementScale = 1.0f, my playerRigidBody does not move at all.

Can someone please explain the correlation of my player movement and movementScale ? What are ideal values for movementScale and speed,  such that my PlayerRigidBody moves proportionally, regardless of whatever size I scale my ground to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default Unity scale is 1 unit = 1 meter (this can be changed in the project settings). The position data returned in the Tango Pose data converts 1 meter in the real world into 1 unit of movement (I'm not sure if it takes into account the project settings).

This means if your Tango world is 50 units long you would need to move 50 meters with your Tango device to cover the length. As this can be impractical the movementScale variable provides a multiplier. So if movementScale is 10, when you walk 5 meters real world you have moved 50 units in the Unity world.

Comment: That makes sense. Some follow up questions

1) If I set my movementScale = 1.0f, then why doesn'y my player move at all? Shouldnt it atleast move in as per real world movements ?

2) What role does the variable 'movement' play in FixedUpdate ? I thought the 5f that we multiply is the speed with which the player will move. 

// Normalise the movement vector and make it proportional to the speed per second.

movement = movement.normalized *5f * Time.deltaTime;

If I increase my movement scale and also my speed then player will just rush through, wouldnt it ? 

Thanks